# Load second app interface in a segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue, watchkit, apple-watch

Basically what I want to do is depicted in the image below:

However this only loads the middle and third interface, the first is hidden both from swiping onto and in the circle indicators at the bottom.

[image: Segue depiction]

I'd like to be able to load the second interface and swipe left for the first and swipe right for the third.  Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm in xcode - these relationship segues seem to do the trick but they are uni-directional.  I wanted to begin the app from the second screen... have I used the wrong type of segue?

Comment: Why is everyone talking about UIViewControllers and custom transitions? This is an Apple Watch question, and none of that applies here. That said, @Evernoob could try setting the Main entry point to the first controller, then have the second controller immediately call `becomeCurrentPage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building my first Apple Watch app over here :)

Looks like there is a concept of UINavigationController-ish behaviour built into the WKInterfacesController.

Take a look at: [pushControllerWithName(_:context:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/pushControllerWithName:context:)

And from some docs I found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/InterfaceStyles.html):

> Hierarchical. This style is suited for apps with more complex data models or apps whose data is more hierarchical. A hierarchical interface always starts with a single root interface controller. In that interface controller, you provide controls that, when tapped, push new interface controllers onto the screen.

EDIT:
Looking into this some more. WatchKit is currently very limited by the looks.

The best solutions I could come up with was to add the three InterfaceController, with segues is between. Left -> Main -> Right.

[image]

Then assign a custom SKInterfaceController for Main:

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {  
  override init() {
    super.init()
    becomeCurrentPage()
  } 
}
```

This creates an annoying animation in the beginning where you will see "Left" on start and how "Main" is animated pushed in. I don't see any better way to do this at this early stage of WatchKit.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty disappointing.  There seems to be very limited functionality available with the watch at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The placement of the ViewControllers have no real "physical" meaning.

A segue (the arrows) simply defines a way to navigate from "this" ViewController to another one.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/81880/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-2

It is possible to create as many segues from one ViewController to other ViewControllers as needed. You can name these segues, and trigger the one you want from storyboard send events or code for specific events (like swipe gestures).

To get the animation of actually sliding the view to the left would require a custom transition:

http://mathewsanders.com/animated-transitions-in-swift/

Comment: The question is about WatchKit `WKInterfaceController` pages, not `UIViewController`. Also, the Watch doesn't support custom transitions.

Comment: Sorry missed that part :)